# body tag not visible in screen ( Nextjs )

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

> `<body><div id="__next"><div>DIbakar Jayjot</div></div></body>`

I am learning nextjs and this code is visible in ELEMENT section in developer mode but body div tag not visible. Help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by _"body div tag not visible"_?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros body is not seen in code but seen only in browser

Answer (score 0):

Try to add style to the div you want to see, like width, height, background-color, so on.